# Para que serve a atribuição em parâmetro de Action, método?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Me surgiu uma dúvida em relação a alguns códigos que encontrei em um projeto de um ex-funcionário da empresa. Trata-se de um código que contem atribuição nos parâmetros das variáveis. Abaixo segue um exemplo:

```
public ActionResult Teste(long id = 0, String tema = "")
{
    //Lógica
}
```

Minha dúvida é para que serve a atribuição - `long id = 0, String tema = ""` se nesse contexto é realmente atribuição nos códigos. Praticamente todas as `Actions` e vários métodos contém essa forma de declaração.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## [Parâmetros opcionais](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/dd264739.aspx)

A atribuição no parâmetro existe para que, caso ao ser chamado a `Action` `Teste` e não sejam passados os parâmetros `id` e `tema`, a `Action` atribua os valores default 0 e "" respectivamente.

No exemplo abaixo o valor o valor do id será 1 e do tema "azul":

```
@Html.Action("Teste", new { id = 1, tema = "azul" });
```

Porém nesse próximo exemplo ele irá assumir os valores `default`: o id será `0` e o tema "".

```
@Html.Action("Teste");
```