# O que é um parâmetro de entrada com igualdade (operador de atribuição)?

Tags: c#, .net, operadores, método, parâmetros

Tenho uma função definida da seguinte maneira:

```
public classeDeRetorno nomeDaFunção(string param1, string param2, string param3 = "")
```

O que significa o `param3 = ""`? Ele iguala o parâmetro a `""`?

Comment: Não domino c# mas me parece ser um valor padrao, caso o parametro não seja definido.

Comment: então se vier `null` fica igual a esse valor, senão fica com o valor da origem?

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Para que serve a atribuição em parâmetro de Action, método?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/70446/para-que-serve-a-atribui%c3%a7%c3%a3o-em-par%c3%a2metro-de-action-m%c3%a9todo)

Comment: @Ack Lay, é parecida sim, mas com esse título não me apareceu nas sugestões.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note que isso não é igualdade, é o operador de atribuição.

Isso é um parâmetro com valor padrão (*default*). Se não for passado um argumento para preenchê-lo, esse valor é usado nessa variável. Ele atribui um valor à variável na falta do argumento que deveria atribuir um valor para ela durante a chamada do método.

O nome mais correto para o recurso é [*optional arguments*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx), já que ele permite que alguns argumentos não precisem ser passados e o método assume um valor.

Só pode ser usado nos últimos parâmetros, não pode ter um parâmetro sem valor padrão depois que tem um com valor *default*.

É um recurso interessante porque evita termos que criar [métodos com assinaturas diferentes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/39870/101) para alcançar o mesmo objetivo e/ou ter que fazer algum algoritmo para resolver a falta do valor.

Veja [Qual a diferença entre parâmetro e argumento?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/32448/101).

Note que se você passar um `null`, o valor da variável será nulo, não pode passar argumento para assumir esse valor. Pode ser visto em:

```
public static void Main() => WriteLine(teste(null));
public static string teste(string x = "xxx") => x;
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/YRKg29). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TjDNzF). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Method/OptionalArguments.cs).

Comment: que resposta completa @bigown! muito obrigado.